# SQLAlchemy eagerloading not working

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to get eagerloading on relationships to work but for the classic "call to database item in loop" problem i.e.

```
users = Session.query(User).all()  # SELECT * from users
for user in users:
    foo(user.exams)  # SELECT * from exams where user_id = ?
```

In order to eagerload instead, here's what I'm doing.

First, here are my model definitions:

```
Base = declarative_base()

class Users(Base):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

class Exams(Base):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'), nullable=False)
    user = db.relationship(
        "Users",
        backref=sqlalchemy.orm.backref(
            'exams',
            cascade='all, delete-orphan'
        ),
        foreign_keys=[user_id]
    )
```

But then, when I actually inspect the raw sql:

```
q = Session().query(Users).join(Users.exams).options(joinedload(Users.exams))
print str(q)
```

I get (formatted):

```
 (SELECT users.id
  FROM users
  JOIN exams ON users.id = exams.user_id)
```

When I was really expecting:

```
(SELECT exams.id, exams.user_id, users.id
 FROM users
 JOIN exams ON users.id = exams.user_id)
```

so that I could do `user.exams` without sending another query to the database. How do I make eagerloading work?

Answer (score 1):

It should be just:

```
q = Session().query(Users).options(joinedload('exams'))
```

Comment: That's still giving me the raw SQL "SELECT users.id FROM users
  JOIN exams ON users.id = exams.user_id" :/ I am following this http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/loading_relationships.html#the-zen-of-eager-loading

Comment: do you want to get result then use `.all()` `Session().query(Users).options(joinedload('exams')).all()`